# Censor Plugin or Extension for VLC Media Player

Tags: windows, plugins, lua, vlc

I'm having an idea to create a Censor Plugin/Extension for VLC Player..

**Problem Scenario :**

An Adult-Scene for 1 minute in a nice movie makes it not watchable with Family.

**My Solution :**

Create a Plugin/Extension which does the following

- Reads time positions from a file similar to subtitle files
- Skip these time positions (which are adult or inappropriate) when playing

**Help i needed :**

I searched in Google and in videolan website, But can't find an exact solution

- Are there already similar Plugins available?
- Where should i start?

Please help me if you could guys.. thanks..

Comment: anything new you found in these 8 years. @Dreamer

Answer (score 1):

Same looking for having/developing Exact same solution. This might be helpful to you.

http://code.google.com/p/movie-content-editor/

Comment: but its empty now, is there an alternative, or someone has it?

Answer (score 1):

A similar thing is also available on github:

https://github.com/rdp/sensible-cinema

You may also want to read this discussion thread:

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=89466

Answer (score 0):

finding great similar answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/679434)

---

If you chop random bytes out the movie is likely not playable. The player might crash or fail to resynchronize the stream – the video might just stop. Plus, you're gonna have a hard time figuring out where the "adult" bytes are, so to speak.

If you already know where the parts are that you want to cut out, I would edit the file in any of the [numerous video editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software). Even Windows Movie Maker or iMovie would do the job, and those are easily available on both major OSes.

---

This is a requested feature for VLC. Not really anything user-friendly out there. Still, VLC offers the possibility to create playlists in a certain format that would mute or skip parts of a file. This is called [XSPF](https://wiki.videolan.org/XSPF). You might be able to figure out the proper format for this.

Also, there's [movie-content-editor](https://code.google.com/p/movie-content-editor/):

> A VLC based editor built in python that allows users to create and use custom filter files to make movies more family friendly. Allows users to have the player automatically mute specific words or skip certain scenes based on the content of those scenes.

And [sensible-cinema](https://github.com/rdp/sensible-cinema):

> Clean Editing Movie Player allows you watch edited movies by applying delete lists (EDL's) (i.e. "mute out" or "cut out" scenes) to DVD's/files, with preliminary support for also applying them to arbitrary web/internet based players like netflix instant, hulu/hulu plus etc

See also these threads on The VideoLAN Forums:

- [auto skip unwanted parts of a video](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=76253&start=0)
- [Clearplay-like (content filter) module exists?](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=89466)